# Convert list of tuples into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to convert my list of tuples 'L' into a dictionary. I am trying to write some code that will add element[5] to my value when the same key (in element[1]) is looped instead of replacing the value.

```
L = [('super mario land 2: 6 golden coins','GB',1992,'adventure','nintendo',11180000.0),
 ('sonic the hedgehog 2', 'GEN', 1992, 'platform', 'sega', 6020000.0),
 ("kirby's dream land", 'GB', 1992, 'platform', 'nintendo', 5130000.0),
 ("the legend of zelda: link's awakening",'GB',1992,'action','nintendo',3840000.0),
 ('mortal kombat', 'GEN', 1992, 'fighting', 'arena entertainment', 2670000.0)]


D = {}

for element in L:

    D[element[1]] = element[5]




Dictionary I want:
    D = { 'GB': 20150000.0,
          'GEN': 8690000 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

L = [('super mario land 2: 6 golden coins','GB',1992,'adventure','nintendo',11180000.0),
 ('sonic the hedgehog 2', 'GEN', 1992, 'platform', 'sega', 6020000.0),
 ("kirby's dream land", 'GB', 1992, 'platform', 'nintendo', 5130000.0),
 ("the legend of zelda: link's awakening",'GB',1992,'action','nintendo',3840000.0),
 ('mortal kombat', 'GEN', 1992, 'fighting', 'arena entertainment', 2670000.0)]

D = defaultdict(float)

for element in L:
    D[element[1]] += element[5]
print(D)
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 0):

```
D = {}
for element in L:
    if element[1] in D:
        D[element[1]] += element[5]
    else:
        D[element[1]] = element[5]
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
for element in L:
    if not element[1] in D.keys():
         D[element[1]] = element[5]
     else:
         D[element[1]] += element[5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for fun, one line solution

```
L = [('super mario land 2: 6 golden coins','GB',1992,'adventure','nintendo',11180000.0), ('sonic the hedgehog 2', 'GEN', 1992, 'platform', 'sega', 6020000.0), ("kirby's dream land", 'GB', 1992, 'platform', 'nintendo', 5130000.0), ("the legend of zelda: link's awakening",'GB',1992,'action','nintendo',3840000.0), ('mortal kombat', 'GEN', 1992, 'fighting', 'arena entertainment', 2670000.0)]

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from functools import reduce
dict([(K,reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[e[-1] for e in T])) for K,T in groupby(sorted(L,key=itemgetter(1)),itemgetter(1))])
```

you get,

```
{'GB': 20150000.0, 'GEN': 8690000.0}
```